# Intellij maven cyrillic symbols printed incorrectly

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, encoding

I run my project using maven lifecycle run. In my code i'm trying to print some Strings which consist of cyrillic symbols from ArrayList like this:

```
cities.forEach(System.out::println);
```

But in console i get something like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA9d8.png)

Also i get same � symbols when printing exception messages which contain cyrillic symbols.

As you can see the line "Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully" is printed correctly, dots and hyphens as well. But all cyrillic symbols are printed like �.

This is my File Encoding Settings: [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFYHY.png), [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fboek.png)

Where can be the problem?

Comment: Try adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart the IDE.

Comment: @CrazyCoder didn't help

Comment: Try adding the same in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | VM Options. If it doesn't help, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and attach a sample project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Tip: Avoid console/shell/terminals if you can: print strings in a file (maybe with an auto-refresh editor): you solve a lot of problems (on setup correctly the terminal/shell/console to interpret input/output as UTF-8 and having the appropriate fonts).